# Underline is drawn outside of rectangle reported by DrawText with DT_CALCRECT

Tags: c++, fonts, mfc, gdi

### Symptoms

I'm having an issue with the recent version 2.0 of the [Lato font](http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/) in its "Regular" variant. This issue doesn't appear with Lato 1.0.

It seems that the underline is drawn 1px below the rectangle reported by `DrawText()` with the `DT_CALCRECT` flag.

In the following screenshots the calculated rectangle is indicated by the blue background. I've added 10px to the right of this rectangle so you can see the discrepancy to the position where the underline is drawn.

Lato 2.0 - underline is incorrectly drawn *outside* of rectangle reported by `DT_CALCRECT`:

[image: Lato 2.0]

Lato 1.0 - underline is correctly drawn *inside* of rectangle reported by `DT_CALCRECT`:

[image: Lato 1.0]

## MCVE

- can be reproduced on Win 10 and Win 7 (Win 8 not tested)
- [Download](http://www.latofonts.com/download/Lato2OFL.zip) and install the Lato 2.0 Regular font (Lato-Regular.ttf).
- Create a dialog based MFC application using the wizard and replace the `OnPaint()` handler of the dialog with the sample code.

Sample code for `OnPaint()`:

```
CPaintDC dc{ this };

CRect rect; GetClientRect( &rect );

LOGFONTW lf{};
wcscpy_s( lf.lfFaceName, L"Lato" );
lf.lfHeight = 20 * 10;  // tenths of a point
lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
lf.lfUnderline = TRUE;

CFont font;
VERIFY( font.CreatePointFontIndirect( &lf ) );

const int saved = dc.SaveDC();

dc.SelectObject( &font );
dc.SetBkMode( TRANSPARENT );
dc.SetTextColor( RGB( 0, 0, 0 ) );  

const CString text = L"Hello Lato";
const DWORD dtFlags = 0;

// Calculate the size required by the text and fill this rectangle
CRect textRect = rect;
dc.DrawText( text, textRect, dtFlags | DT_CALCRECT );
textRect.right += 10;
dc.FillSolidRect( 0, 0, textRect.right, textRect.bottom, RGB( 180, 180, 255 ) );

// Actually draw the text
dc.DrawTextW( text, rect, dtFlags );

if( saved )
    dc.RestoreDC( saved );
```

### Question

Do you think this is an issue in my code, a bug in the OS or a bug in the font?

Unfortunately I can't just use Lato 1.0 as Lato 2.0 added support for many new languages my software needs to support.

Comment: Don't have time to dig into this at the moment, but the internal Windows implementation for `DrawText` doesn't do anything magic. It just draws a line underneath the text extent, after drawing the text. So the difference will almost certainly be your fonts. Lato 2.0 has a lower baseline than Lato 1.0. You should be able to check this out in a font viewer program that displays all the gory details about OTF/TTF font files.

Comment: Does the value returned by first `DrawText` match height of updated `textRect`?

Comment: @VTT, yes both values match.

Comment: For me it looks like a bug in the font! Just my 2 cents.