# Pixel exact string measurement

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

I try to compute the exact pixel size of a given text (e.g. to `InvalidateRect` or create a bitmap of sufficient size later on). I do not have a device context at the moment of measurement, so I have to resort to a memory device context.

I found that [`DrawText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498(v=vs.85).aspx) with `DT_CALCRECT` apparently returns the "advance width" and not the actual width occupied by pixels when drawn. Compensating this using [`GetCharABCWidths`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd144857(v=vs.85).aspx) (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374094(v=vs.85).aspx) for a explanation of ABC widths) is at best another approximation since e.g. possibly the ABC widths of the second glyph is decisive if the first glyph is very narrow (even it it "seems to give good results" for my example cases), not to mention font smoothing.

Thus, I tried using [`SetBoundsRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162966(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`GetBoundsRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144854(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
auto MeasureTest = [](int x, int y) {
    auto dc = CreateCompatibleDC(nullptr);
    SetBoundsRect(dc, nullptr, DCB_ENABLE | DCB_RESET);
    auto const text = L"Test";
    RECT rect{x, y, x, y};
    DrawText(dc, text, 4, &rect, DT_NOCLIP);
    GetBoundsRect(dc, &rect, 0);
    return rect;
};
```

(Please ignore memory leaks. I verified that all those functions return what I would expect from what I have read in MSDN.)

Using this routine, I get the following results:

```
MeasureTest(0, 0);       // returns (0,0)-(1,1); reasonable (dc holds a 1x1 bitmap)
```

As noted, this seemed reasonable since the dc contains a 1x1 bitmap initially. However, the following two calls indicate that at least some measurement has been done:

```
MeasureTest(-100, -100); // returns (0,0)-(-72,-84), i.e. an empty rect
MeasureTest(100, 100);   // returns (100,100)-(1,1), i.e. an empty rect
```

I tried selecting a sufficiently large bitmap (1000x1000 px) into the device context before drawing, which apparently gave correct results. But this, of course, raises the initial question: how many pixels does the string occupy?

Is there a reliable way to determine the *exact* pixel size for a string?

Comment: Do you know `GetTextExtentPoint32` function?

Comment: Why is `DrawText()` with `DT_CALCRECT` not good enough? The difference to the actual pixel width is usually not very big.

Comment: @i486 Yes, but it does not support multiline text and suffers from the same problem as `DrawText` with `DT_CALCRECT`.

Comment: @zett42 As said, I would like to have the exact pixel width: If I use it to `InvalidateRect` or to create a sufficiently large bitmap, there may be some pixels clipped.

Comment: I'm sure the width of the rectangle is at least as wide as the text, so there won't be clipping. I've used it in similar way to determine the size of a bitmap buffer that will fit the text and never got any issues with clipping.

Comment: I just remember that I actually had an [issue with `DT_CALCRECT`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45694393/7571258), but it most likely was due to incorrect metrics stored in the font file. Maybe you experience a similar case here. Do you have issues with all fonts or just a specific one?

Comment: @phimuemue Probably you can split the lines of text and call `GetTextExtentPoint32 ` for each line.

Comment: @i486 I actually thought about this. But `GetTextExtentPoint32` apparently also gives the advance width instead of the "consumed-pixels-width" and moreover, I am not sure whether just adding line heights is precise enough.

Comment: `GetTextExtentPoint32` will always provide coordinates, that are at least large enough to hold the entire text. If you use it as the argument to `InvalidateRect`, does it really matter, whether the rectangle is sometimes a bit larger than the actual invalid area? For rendering to a bitmap, using a bitmap that's a bit larger than necessary isn't fatal either. If you absolutely need a bitmap that is no larger than the text it represents, you could scan lines and columns from either edge to find those, that are completely empty and prune those.

Comment: Did you do anything to verify whether the Set/GetBoundsRect approach gave correct answers or did they match the answer that DT_CALCRECT gave?  Is the app marked high-DPI aware?  Does turning off ClearType make a difference?

Comment: @IInspectable I think that `GetTextExtentPoint32` does not do this (I tried using it and realized that the coordinates are a bit off, which is why I went to `DrawText` with `DT_CALCRECT`. Can you provide any documentation or evidence for your claim? (Because if documentation somewhere explicitly states this, I am happy to dig into that deeper.)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy To be honest I did not investigate too deeply (because of the apparently required sufficiently large bitmap).